# Socket connection on NanoFramework

Tags: nanoframework

I am having a problem where I cannot Telnet onto my Nucleo-F746ZG using the following code:

I see DHCP assigns a valid IP address which means the board can see the network (and router) but when I use a Telnet client to connect. The code never leaves listener.Accept. The same code runs fine on Windows under .NET Framework.

```
        private void ConnectionListenerThread()
    {
        byte [] buff = new byte[ 1024 ];
        int received;

        //
        // Grab a collection of available network interfaces.
        //
        NetworkInterface[] nis = NetworkInterface.GetAllNetworkInterfaces();

        //
        // We need at least one interface to continue.
        //
        if ( nis.Length > 0 )
        {
            NetworkInterface ni = nis[0];
            ni.EnableDhcp();

            //
            // Wait to be assigned an IP address.
            //
            while ( ni.IPv4Address == null || ni.IPv4Address.Length == 0 || ni.IPv4Address.Equals( "0.0.0.0" ) )
            {
                Thread.Sleep( 100 );
            }

            Debug.WriteLine( $"DHCP has given us the address {ni.IPv4Address},{ni.IPv4SubnetMask},{ni.IPv4GatewayAddress}" );

            while ( true )
            {
                _clientSocket = null;

                //
                // We now have an IP address allocated so we can await
                // incoming client connections.
                //
                IPEndPoint localEndPoint = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Any, ListeningPort);
                Socket listener = new Socket( localEndPoint.AddressFamily, SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp );

                try
                {
                    listener.Bind( localEndPoint );
                    listener.Listen( 100 );

                    Debug.WriteLine( $"Waiting for an incoming connection on port {ListeningPort}.." );
                    _clientSocket = listener.Accept();
                    Debug.WriteLine( "Connected to a client" );

                    while ( true )
                    {
                        received = _clientSocket.Receive( buff );
                        if ( received > 0 )
                        {
                            OnSerialDataReceived?.Invoke( this, new EventArguments.BytesReceivedEventArgs( buff, received ) );
                        }
                    }
                }
                catch ( Exception ex )
                {
                    Debug.WriteLine( $"Got a network exception: {ex.Message}" );
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

ListeningPort is typically set to 54321.

Here is the system information that shows the version of NanoFramework installed.

```
System Information
HAL build info: nanoCLR running @ ST_NUCLEO144_F746ZG
  Target:   ST_NUCLEO144_F746ZG
  Platform: STM32F7

Firmware build Info:
  Date:     Jul 13 2020
  Type:     MinSizeRel build with ChibiOS v19.1.4.1
  Version:  1.4.590.0
  Compiler: GNU ARM GCC v9.3.1
```

Does anyone have any suggestions on what I am doing wrong ?

Andy

Comment: If you run the the [HTTP listener sample](https://github.com/nanoframework/Samples/tree/master/samples/HTTP/HttpListener) do you experience the same behaviour?

Comment: José, yes the HTTP listener seems to work fine.

Comment: Curiously, I noticed the line ni.EnableAutomaticDns(); in the sample code which I did not have in mine. When I add that line, TeraTerm gives me a "Connection Refused" error message but without that line, TeraTerm gives me a "Connection timed out" error message. Not sure if that is a pointer to what is going on but my code is still stuck at the Accept call :-(

Answer (score 0):

That looks like a bug... Please raise an issue in our GitHub.
Make sure to add a project that reproduces the issue.

Comment: Raised here https://github.com/nanoframework/Home/issues/638